# How to set value from select from one Data Set as parameter in other Data Set in BI Publisher

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

So I have dataset1 that has something like `SELECT userID from table1 where ...` from DataBase1

And I have dataset2 that has some complicated SQL on DataBase2 that must have parameter `... where userID = :userID...`

So how can I pass that `userID` that I get in SQL from DB1 to SQL that I'm running in DB2?

Comment: You have a database link between the two databases?

Comment: I'm not administrating that DB but I guess it's possible, will that work in BI publisher?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question but it seems to me you're really just asking how to join one table in one database to another table in a different database.  And a database link provides a simple way of doing that.  If you can get the join to work in SQL then you can get the join to work in BIP.  But it could also be that my instinct to simplify has made me mis-read your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. Two queries like you mentioned. I have an incoming parameter to select a set from the first table (parent records). And then I pass the userID to the second query (child records). I show how that works in the data structure too, how each parent record can have child records.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<dataTemplate name="DATA_DEFINITION_NAME" version="1.0" defaultPackage="DATA_DEFINITION_CODE">
<properties>
<property name="ENCODING" value="windows-1252"/>
<property name="debug_mode"    value="on" /> 
<property name="scalable_mode" value="on" />
</properties>
<parameters>
<parameter name="i_parameter"   dataType="NUMBER"   />
</parameters>
<dataQuery>
<sqlStatement name="Q_TABLE_1"><![CDATA[select userid, username from table1 where column1 = :i_parameter ]]></sqlStatement>
<sqlStatement name="Q_TABLE_2"><![CDATA[select ValueColumn from table2 where userid = :userid ]]></sqlStatement>
</dataQuery>
<dataStructure>
<group name="users" source="Q_TABLE_1">
<element name="username"          value="username"         /> 
<group name="userdata" source="Q_TABLE_2">
<element name="ValueColumn"                     value="ValueColumn"                />
</group> 
</group>
</dataStructure>
</dataTemplate>
```